# C: FileI/O looping through a file containing a set of numbers to find their squares, cubes, and square roots

Tags: c, file-io

The objective of the program is to read a set of numbers from a text file loop through each number in the file find the Square, Cube, and the Square root of each number and write the new numbers in an output text file.

I've figured out how to read and write to files properly but i cant figure out how to format the loop properly to read each of the number from the input file.

i also attempted to use the "sqrt()" function in math.h, but it did not work correctly i am more concerned with getting the loop working properly first.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <ctype.h>
   #include <math.h>
   #define SIZE 40

  int main(void)
{
char ch, filename[SIZE]; //variables


int i, n, square, cube , sroot;

FILE *fp;
printf("Please enter the filename to read: ");
gets(filename);


if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open the file, %s\n", filename);
}
else
{
    while (fscanf(fp,"%d",&n) == 1)
    {
      for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
      {

      square=n*n;
      cube=square*n;
      sroot= sqrt(n);
      }
}
}


fclose(fp);

char filename2 [SIZE];
FILE *fp2;

fprintf(stdout, "Please enter the file name to write in: "); //asks for file that you want to write to
gets(filename2);

if ((fp2 = fopen(filename2, "w")) == NULL) //"w" for writing
{
    printf("Cannot create the file, %s\n", filename2);
}
else
{
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp2, "%d, %d, %d \n",square, cube, sroot);

    }

}

fclose(fp2); // closing the file
fprintf(stdout, "You are writing to the file, %s is done.\n", filename2);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: why do you need a for loop there? It doesn't match your requirements description.

Comment: The [sqrt](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sqrt.htm) function is defined for double precision floating points, not ints (like the input n). In order to use it, you will have to cast n to a double by doing: `sroot = sqrt((double)n);`

Comment: i thought maybe a for loop would do the calculations for all the numbers in the file currently my program only does the calculations for the last digit in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Open both files and check for success. Then as values are read from the input file, print the results to the output file. Close both files.
Use `fgets` instead of `gets`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SIZE 40

int main(void)
{
    char filename[SIZE] = {'\0'};
    char filename2 [SIZE] = {'\0'};
    int n = 0, square = 0, cube = 0 , sroot = 0;
    FILE *fp2;
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Please enter the filename to read: ");
    fgets ( filename, SIZE, stdin);
    filename[strcspn ( filename, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open the file, %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    printf( "Please enter the file name to write in: "); //asks for file that you want to write to
    fgets ( filename2, SIZE, stdin);
    filename2[strcspn ( filename2, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline

    if ((fp2 = fopen(filename2, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open the file, %s\n", filename2);
        fclose ( fp);
        return 2;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp,"%d",&n) == 1)//read a number from input
    {
        square=n*n;
        cube=square*n;
        sroot= (int)sqrt((double)n);
        //print results to output
        fprintf(fp2, "%d, %d, %d \n",square, cube, sroot);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    printf( "You are writing to the file, %s is done.\n", filename2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C library function fscanf() - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm

> This function returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

The loop doesn't work, because the number of input items is 1 only at the first iteration, afterwards it's more, therefore it doesn't enter the **while loop**.

If that's what you want it to do, there's no point in putting that while there, if you want to check if there's anything to read from that file, you can simply put an if. Otherwise, that might be your problem.